# Conditionally send "to" "cc" and "bcc" emails based on whether they exists in certain spreadsheet columns

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to add a line to my MailApp.sendEmail code where I cc emails from two different reference columns in a google sheet document.  Is there a way to do this?

In addition, I want to be able to reference a column to bcc on my email, but not all of the cells are filled.  Is there a way to to reference the column and have it ignore the blank cells to send out the email with only the bcc people I have listed in my column?

Finally, is it possible to put multiple emails in the same cell and not freak out the script?  When I currently do this, I get an error saying, "someone@gmail.com; anothersomeone@gmail.com is not a valid email."

Here is the code I have now:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: values[i][1],
  cc: values[i][2],
  // how do I reference multiple columns (2 and 3) here???
  bcc: values[i][3],
  //how do I get the code to ignore blank cells & is there a code so I put multiple emails in a cell in column 4
  subject: "Weekly math grade update for " + values[i][0],
  htmlBody: body,
});
```

Comment: Currently you have an object literal inside the `sendEmail()` method.  Create a variable for an object `var mailObj; mailObj = {htmlBody:body};`  Then use a conditional test for whether the cc: and bcc: properties get set.  `if (values[i][1]) {mailObj.to = values[i][1];}`  And then:  `MailApp.sendEmail(mailObj)`  Of course you'll need to add the subject and "to" property also.